# Changing logo and font in navbar after scrolling in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, navbar

I,m changing navbar background color after scrolling down with jquery, but I don't know, how to change logo (logo color) and font color in the same moment when the navbar color changes...

**Here is the code:**
http://www.bootply.com/YIzwEneMF7

Thank for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer: http://www.bootply.com/jEfJnFXeR8

Your mistake is this: `.navbar-custom .scrolled { color: red;}`

The `scrolled` class is adding to navbar-custom not inside it.

Add the following code to css

```
.navbar-custom.scrolled .navbar-nav > li > a { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code in your jQuery if statement, this changes your font-color,

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > startY){
    $('.navbar, .navbar-custom').addClass("scrolled");
  **$('.nav a').css('color','black');**
}
else{
    $('.navbar, .navbar-custom').removeClass("scrolled");
   **$('.nav a').css('color','white');**
}
```